# Background color of the page when an alert is showing

Tags: javascript

I currently have the following code that makes a prompt show up when trying to access a page

```
    <script>
var password = "1234";
if(prompt("Enter password:", "") !== password) window.location = "/";
</script>
```

What I want to know is if there is a way to change the background color of the page while the prompt is showing up:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LHBT.png)

Comment: You could use element.classList.add / remove / toggle to control the style using JS.  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp